# Show that $\ell^{\alpha}\subseteq \ell^{1}$, where $\ell^{\alpha}:=\{(b_n)_{n\geq 0}\mid \sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}|b_n| ^\alpha<\infty\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

For $\alpha>0$, let $\ell^{\alpha}:=\{(b_n)_{n\geq 0}\mid \sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}|b_n| ^\alpha<\infty\}$. If $\alpha\in (0,1]$, how to check that $\ell^{\alpha}\subseteq \ell^1$?

What I think: Assume $\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}|b_n| ^\alpha<\infty$. Then, there exists $N\geq 1$ such that $\sum_{n= N+1}^{\infty}|b_n| ^\alpha<1$. What to do from this part? If I can show that (help needed here for justification) $|b_n|<1$ for all (or infinitely many?) $n$ then we would get $|b_n|\leq |b_n|^{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |b_n|^{\alpha}<\infty$ implies that $|b_n|^{\alpha}\to 0$, and this implies $|b_n|\to 0$. Hence there is some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_n|<1$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Since $\alpha\leq 1$ and $|b_n|<1$ it follows that $|b_n|\leq |b_n|^{\alpha}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Now by the comparison test $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|<\infty$.

Comment: Wow... I totally forgot [Term Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test). You wrote "... and this implies $|b_n|\to \infty$", could you please explain why?

Comment: @James It was a typo. It is $|b_n|\to 0$ of course.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf{b}:\mathbb{Z}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is in $\ell_\alpha$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\mathbf{b}(n)|^\alpha=0$ and so, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\mathbf{b}(n)|=0$. It follows that there is $M>0$ such that $|\mathbf{b}(n)|\leq M$ for all $n$. Hence

$$ |\mathbf{b}(n)|=|\mathbf{b}(n)|^\alpha|\mathbf{b}(n)|^{1-\alpha}\leq  M^{1-\alpha}|\mathbf{b}(n)|^\alpha,\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$$

whence we conclude that $\mathbf{b}\in\ell_1$.